# Student status form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, pdo

I'm programming a system and I want to know if this is the correct way or if there is a better way to do it.

Container:

I have more fields but I only added one to show you the container.

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return submitForm();" role="form" id="div-studentStatus">                     
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Status:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5 text-primary" id="div-studentStatus">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo  $_POST['id']; ?>" id="studentId">
            <select class='form-control input-sm'  id="studentStatus">
                <option value="1">Activo</option>
                <option value="0">Inactivo</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" align="center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-sm" id="statusSaveButton">Guardar</button></div>                                    
        <div class="col-sm-1">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>                                                      
</form>
```

When the user clicks on `statusSaveButton`, I append a confirmation button (`statusSaveButtonYes` and `statusSaveButtonNo`). I only add the action if the user clicks on YES.

```
$(document).on('click','#statusSaveButton',function() {
    $('#studentStatus').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#statusSaveButton').prop('disabled', true);
    var studentStatus = $("#studentStatus").val();
    if ($("#studentStatusConfirm").length) {
        $("#studentStatusConfirm").html('<div class="col-sm-12">Are you sure you want to modify the record?&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" id="statusSaveButtonYes" style="width:30px">Yes</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="statusSaveButtonNo" style="width:30px">No</button></div>');
        $("#studentStatusConfirm").show();
    } else {
        $("#div-studentStatus").append('<div class="form-group" id="studentStatusConfirm"><div class="col-sm-12">¿Estas seguro que deseas modificar el status del alumno?&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" id="statusSaveButtonYes" style="width:30px">Si</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="statusSaveButtonNo" style="width:30px">No</button></div></div>');      
    }
}); 
$(document).on('click','#statusSaveButtonYes',function() {
    var studentId = $("#studentId").val();
    var studentStatus = $("#studentStatus").val();  
    $.post("content/studentsAction.php", {action:"editStudentStatus", studentId:studentId, studentStatus:studentStatus}, function(data){
        if (data != "Successful") {
            $("#studentStatusConfirm").html('<div class="col-sm-12 text-danger">'+data+'</div>');
            $("#statusSaveButtons").show();
            $('#studentStatus').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#statusSaveButton').prop('disabled', false);             
        } else {
            $("#studentStatusConfirm").html('<div class="col-sm-12 text-success">Success.</div>');
            $("#statusSaveButtons").show();
            $('#studentStatus').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#statusSaveButton').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Action (content/studentsAction.php):

I have 8 different actions in this page (I only add one): change status, change level, change name, etc. I control the action with the `$_POST["action"]` variable.

```
<?php
$regex_studentId = '/^[0-9]{1,12}$/';
$regex_studentStatus = '/^[01]{1}$/';
if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
    if ($_POST["action"] == "editStudentStatus") {
        if ((isset($_POST["studentId"])) and (isset($_POST["studentStatus"]))) {
            if ((preg_match($regex_studentId, $_POST["studentId"])) and (preg_match($regex_studentStatus, $_POST["studentStatus"]))) {
                $updateStudentStatus = updateStudentStatus($_POST["studentId"],$_POST["studentStatus"]);
                if ($updateStudentStatus) {
                    echo "Successful";
                } else {
                    echo "Error.";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Error.";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error.";
        }
} else {
    echo "Error.";
}
?>
```

Database:

```
function updateStudentStatus($studentId,$studentStatus) {
    include ("./businesslogic/dbconnection/cfg.php");
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$server.';dbname='.$db,$db_user,$db_password);
    $string = "update students set student_status = :studentStatus where student_id = :studentId";
    $sql = $db->prepare($string);
    $sql->bindParam(':studentId',$studentId);
    $sql->bindParam(':studentStatus',$studentStatus);   
    if ($sql->execute()) {
        $db = null;
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        $db = null;
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: This: `echo  $_POST['id'];` is vulnerable to XSS. Use `htmlspecialchars` to [prevent XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php).

Answer (score 2):

**Variable definition**

You sometimes define variables in camelCase and sometimes with underscores. I recommend to use one spelling type only.

**PHP**

If function `updateStudentStatus` is not part of a class consider developing a database class that handles it. Another option is to add a `save` function to each of your Model classes. This makes your code easier to read. For more details check mvc pattern.

In the `updateStudentStatus` function you establish a new database connection with each call. You can avoid it by promoting the function to a proper class and define a global attribute holding your database connection.

**JS**

In your javascript you have html code. I recommend to either load it with rest of the dom and hide it by default or load it using ajax. I personally compare it with inline css.

**HTML**

In html form you have an attribute `onsubmit`. It should be in a javascript file. I compare it with inline css as well.

**"QUOTES"**

Also see CodeX answer.

As tim mentioned `$_POST` and other variables not provided by yourself have to be validated and parsed by htmlspecialchars e.g. to avoid XSS.

**A bit about security**

I've added this section due to mentioned XSS.

Security is a very complex topic and must not be underestimated. There are a lot of options to implement and grant security. What kind of options you choose depends on your time/budget but also kind of project and data that are going to be stored in your database. I kindly ask you to think wise about the data that will be saved in the database and make researches about proper security measures.

There are a lot of PHP Frameworks. I recommend to take a look into some of them as those provide security standards.

Answer (score 1):

This portion of code is very messy and has a lot of unnecessary `else { echo error }`

```
<?php
$regex_studentId = '/^[0-9]{1,12}$/';
$regex_studentStatus = '/^[01]{1}$/';
if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
    if ($_POST["action"] == "editStudentStatus") {
        if ((isset($_POST["studentId"])) and (isset($_POST["studentStatus"]))) {
            if ((preg_match($regex_studentId, $_POST["studentId"])) and (preg_match($regex_studentStatus, $_POST["studentStatus"]))) {
                $updateStudentStatus = updateStudentStatus($_POST["studentId"],$_POST["studentStatus"]);
                if ($updateStudentStatus) {
                    echo "Successful";
                } else {
                    echo "Error.";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Error.";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error.";
        }
} else {
    echo "Error.";
}
?>
```

This is much cleaner and should work just the same:

```
<?php
$regex_studentId = '/^[0-9]{1,12}$/';
$regex_studentStatus = '/^[01]{1}$/';


if (isset($_POST["action"], $_POST["studentId"], $_POST["studentStatus"]) && $_POST["action"] == "editStudentStatus") {
    if ((preg_match($regex_studentId, $_POST["studentId"])) and (preg_match($regex_studentStatus, $_POST["studentStatus"]))) {
                $updateStudentStatus = updateStudentStatus($_POST["studentId"],$_POST["studentStatus"]);
                if ($updateStudentStatus) {
                    echo "Successful";
                } 
                else {
                    echo "Error";   
                }
            } 

}
```

I think this will help your work flow and make the code easier to read, not just for you but for anyone else that might need to work with it.